# postgresql - transaction log - versioning?

Tags: postgresql

Is it possible to "version" your database so that any change can be reviewed or roll backed? Obviously backups are important but being able to go back to any previous state of the database (at least say  with in the last 2 days) would be very helpful. I am not a database administrator but I am developing an application that needs some fault tolerance. If it is possible can you point me in the right direction for information? If is not possible what are my options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should setup point in time recovery. take a look,
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/continuous-archiving.html